# C++ run time error with quick sort algorithm throwing stack dump error

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

The code works fine when I try **size = 20000** and it seems to fail when I try **size = 50000** giving me the following error:

> 2 [] cppapplication_4 7628 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to cppapplication_4.exe.stackdump

```
long long compares; // for counting compares
long long swaps; // for counting swaps
bool counted_less(int n1, int n2) {
    ++compares;
    return n1 < n2;
}

void counted_swap(int& n1, int& n2) {
    ++swaps;
    int t = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = t;
}

int* partition(int* start, int* stop) {
    int noUse=99;
    int* pivot = (stop - 1); // you can randomly pick one as the pivot
    int* i = start;
    int* j = stop - 1;
    for (;;) {
        while (*i < *pivot && i < stop)
        {
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            ++i;
        }
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
        // skip "low" on left side
        while (*j >= *pivot && j > start) {
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            --j;
        }
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);

        // skip "high" on right side
        if (i >= j) 
        {
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            counted_less(noUse,noUse);
        }
        swap(*i, *j);
        counted_swap(noUse,noUse);// swap out-of-place items
    }
    swap(*(stop - 1), *i); 
    counted_swap(noUse,noUse);// swap pivot to the final place i
    return i;

}
void quickSort(int* start, int* stop) {
    int noUse=99;
    if (start>= stop){
        counted_less(noUse,noUse);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        counted_less(noUse,noUse);
    }
    int* pivot = partition(start,stop);
    quickSort(start, pivot);
    quickSort((pivot +1), stop);
}

int main()
{
    int size = 20000;
    int* data = new int[size];
     for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) data[i] = i;
     quickSort(data, data + size);
}
```

I think the error means that I am  going over a data type storage limit, I think the problem was with me using int so I changed all the int to long long and that still didn't fix it. And by the logic of the code I don't think that we are changing the size of an array. So I am not sure what caused the error.

Comment: Operator `new` can throw `std::bad_alloc`, check if it is not an issue in your case. Also you can compile your program without optimization, with debug symbols and investigate stack trace - it will point where your program crashed.

Comment: Were you provided with `counted_less`? It seems strange that you are calling it with garbage and ignoring it's return value every time

Comment: I would expect it to be used like `if (!counted_less(start, stop)) return;` and `while(counted_less(*i, *pivot) && counted_less(*i, stop)) ++i;`

Comment: @Caleth yea that is how I was suppose to do it, but I was lazy and did it that way instead

Comment: As a side note: Beside of one `new` I don't see a reason, why this is tagged as C++, it is plain C.

Comment: @glockm15 If I were marking this assignment, you'd get 0 for that

Comment: @hellow because it's being supplied to a C++ compiler

Comment: You need to check your boundaries *before* dereferencing.

Comment: It runs to completion [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e3708e7fe16089)

Comment: Start with smaller test cases - 0,1,2,... elements - and find the smallest test case that causes a problem. Then you can trace through your algorithm by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting a stack overflow. That's why recursion is bad.

As a temporary workaround try increasing the stack size by linking with `--stack 16777216`:

```
$ g++ -Wl,--stack,16777216  . . .
```

**== EDIT ==**

Also your choice of pivot at `(end - 1)` is not good. Try setting the pivot in the middle.

```
    int* pivot = (stop - start)/sizeof(int*)/2 + start;
```

Comment: Looks like this. When I ran it and [printed the counts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e3708e7fe16089) it looks like we are in the pathological bad pivot case

Comment: Sorry I am not very good at this programming stuff, where do I use that code to increase stack size?

Comment: That depends on how you run compile and run your code. What tool do you use for that?

Comment: Just the netbeans

Comment: Try: project properties -> linker -> additional options, add `-Wl,--stack,16777216`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. But is this my computer's problem and doesn't have enough memory?

Comment: Application stack size has a limit, it's not related to your PC memory, but is much less. On Windows the default is 1 MB. You can increase it if you need more stack, that's what that linker option does.